# Intersecting matplotlib graph with unsorted data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

When plotting some points with `matplotlib` I encountered some strange behavior when creating a graph. Here is the code to produce this graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
desc_x =[4000,3000,2000,2500,2750,2250,2300,2400,2450,2350]
rmse_desc = [.31703 , .31701, .31707, .31700, .31713, .31698, .31697, .31688, .31697, .31699]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

fig.suptitle('title')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

ax.plot(desc_x, rmse_desc, 'b', label='desc' )
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the graph it creates

[image: graph with lines]

As you can tell, this graph has intersecting lines, something one doesn't see in a line graph. When I isolate the points, and don't draw the lines, I get this result:

[image: graph without lines]

As you can tell, there is a way to connect these points without intersecting lines.

Why does matplotlib do this? I think I could fix it by not having my xcolumn be unsorted, but if I sort it, I will lose the mapping from x1 to y1.

Comment: Is there any functional relationship between `desc_x` and `rmse_desc`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can maintain the order using numpy's [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) function.

Argsort "...returns an array of indices of the same shape as a that index data along the given axis in sorted order.", so we can use this to re-order the x and y coordinates together. Here's how it's done:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

desc_x =[4000,3000,2000,2500,2750,2250,2300,2400,2450,2350]
rmse_desc = [.31703 , .31701, .31707, .31700, .31713, .31698, .31697, .31688, .31697, .31699]

order = np.argsort(desc_x)
xs = np.array(desc_x)[order]
ys = np.array(rmse_desc)[order]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

fig.suptitle('title')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

ax.plot(xs, ys, 'b', label='desc' )
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Was my guess correct, that the graph looked so weird because the x vals were unsorted?

Comment: Ah, yes that is correct. Matplotlib will draw lines between each pair in the order you have provided.

Comment: You can also do something similar with `xs, ys = zip(*sorted(zip(desc_x, rmse_desc)))`, but I prefer the numpy way

Comment: i couldn't understand the reason for weired graph. I had one categorical variable(month; x) and number of faults( y). both were sorted still i got same weired graph.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140745/matplotlib-pyplot-plot-function-shows-incorrect-sequence-of-points?noredirect=1#comment97021695_55140745