# Solving coefficients of data set using curve_fit from scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have an array `A` exported from excel, containing data values as shown. 1st column `x` and 2nd column `y` are dependent variables, while 3rd column `z` are independent variables (the output).

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

Data = open_workbook("simple.xls")
sheet = Data.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

A=[]

# Read row by row
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    rowValues = sheet.row_values(rownum)
    A.append(rowValues)

A = np.array(A)

A=
[[  0.00000000e+00   1.49761692e-05   0.00000000e+00]
 [  8.85000000e+02   1.49761692e-05   6.41362500e-02]
 [  1.48500000e+03   1.49761692e-05   1.19340000e-01]
 [  2.09000000e+03   1.49761692e-05   1.58760000e-01]
 [  3.36000000e+03   1.49761692e-05   2.08080000e-01]
 [  3.87000000e+03   1.49761692e-05   2.16933750e-01]
 [  6.48000000e+03   1.49761692e-05   2.46746250e-01]
 [  8.22000000e+03   1.49761692e-05   2.54700000e-01]
 [  1.05300000e+04   1.49761692e-05   2.59470000e-01]
 [  1.58250000e+04   1.49761692e-05   2.62035000e-01]
 [  2.37600000e+04   1.49761692e-05   2.68751250e-01]
 [  8.18400000e+04   1.49761692e-05   2.92848750e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   8.57250668e-06   0.00000000e+00]
 [  6.75000000e+02   8.57250668e-06   4.97436412e-02]
 [  1.27500000e+03   8.57250668e-06   1.27749375e-01]
 [  1.88000000e+03   8.57250668e-06   1.88617039e-01]
 [  3.15000000e+03   8.57250668e-06   2.65089780e-01]
 [  3.66000000e+03   8.57250668e-06   2.90344849e-01]
 [  6.27000000e+03   8.57250668e-06   3.36295316e-01]
 [  8.01000000e+03   8.57250668e-06   3.42702439e-01]
 [  1.03200000e+04   8.57250668e-06   3.65205982e-01]
 [  1.56150000e+04   8.57250668e-06   3.67269626e-01]
 [  2.35500000e+04   8.57250668e-06   3.87296798e-01]
 [  8.16300000e+04   8.57250668e-06   4.43486869e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   4.26671486e-06   0.00000000e+00]
 [  4.65000000e+02   4.26671486e-06   2.61407250e-02]
 [  1.06500000e+03   4.26671486e-06   1.22371762e-01]
 [  1.67000000e+03   4.26671486e-06   2.19629475e-01]
 [  2.94000000e+03   4.26671486e-06   3.26680087e-01]
 [  3.45000000e+03   4.26671486e-06   3.34340662e-01]
 [  6.06000000e+03   4.26671486e-06   4.18330575e-01]
 [  7.80000000e+03   4.26671486e-06   4.50631350e-01]
 [  1.01100000e+04   4.26671486e-06   4.55053950e-01]
 [  1.54050000e+04   4.26671486e-06   4.60937587e-01]
 [  2.33400000e+04   4.26671486e-06   5.10770813e-01]
 [  8.14200000e+04   4.26671486e-06   6.12569587e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   2.13335743e-06   0.00000000e+00]
 [  8.55000000e+02   2.13335743e-06   1.03773150e-01]
 [  1.46000000e+03   2.13335743e-06   2.21130000e-01]
 [  2.73000000e+03   2.13335743e-06   3.45515625e-01]
 [  3.24000000e+03   2.13335743e-06   3.85634925e-01]
 [  5.85000000e+03   2.13335743e-06   4.76061300e-01]
 [  7.59000000e+03   2.13335743e-06   4.79220300e-01]
 [  1.51950000e+04   2.13335743e-06   5.24709900e-01]
 [  2.31300000e+04   2.13335743e-06   5.64829200e-01]
 [  8.12100000e+04   2.13335743e-06   6.46568325e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.42359023e-06   0.00000000e+00]
 [  6.45000000e+02   1.42359023e-06   8.03596500e-02]
 [  1.25000000e+03   1.42359023e-06   2.36700000e-01]
 [  2.52000000e+03   1.42359023e-06   4.25941650e-01]
 [  3.03000000e+03   1.42359023e-06   4.61683350e-01]
 [  5.64000000e+03   1.42359023e-06   5.99561100e-01]
 [  7.38000000e+03   1.42359023e-06   6.05952000e-01]
 [  9.69000000e+03   1.42359023e-06   6.16958550e-01]
 [  1.49850000e+04   1.42359023e-06   6.57434250e-01]
 [  2.29200000e+04   1.42359023e-06   6.45954300e-01]
 [  8.10000000e+04   1.42359023e-06   7.79689800e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   9.36010573e-07   0.00000000e+00]
 [  4.35000000e+02   9.36010573e-07   3.40200000e-02]
 [  1.04000000e+03   9.36010573e-07   1.91160000e-01]
 [  2.31000000e+03   9.36010573e-07   3.77640000e-01]
 [  2.82000000e+03   9.36010573e-07   4.44240000e-01]
 [  5.43000000e+03   9.36010573e-07   5.50440000e-01]
 [  7.17000000e+03   9.36010573e-07   5.36580000e-01]
 [  9.48000000e+03   9.36010573e-07   5.83740000e-01]
 [  1.47750000e+04   9.36010573e-07   5.87340000e-01]
 [  2.27100000e+04   9.36010573e-07   6.33060000e-01]
 [  8.07900000e+04   9.36010573e-07   7.36200000e-01]]

x= A[:,0]
y= A[:,1]
z= A[:,2]
```

I have a function that would fit into the data from array A in order to solve for coefficients `a` and `b`.

```
def func(data,a,b):
    return a/(data[:,1]*b)*np.log(1+(data[:,1]*b/a)*(1-np.exp(-a*data[:,0])))
```

The rest of the code shows the initial guess of the coefficients `a` and `b`, the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` function, and `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot the result.

```
guess = [3.0e-5, 128 ]  

print guess, 'initial guessed parameters' 

params, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, A[:,:2], A[:,2], guess)

print params, 'fitted parameters' 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(x,func(A,params[0],params[1]),'-r',x,z,'o') 
plt.title('Plot') 
plt.legend(['Fit', 'Data'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

The result of the plot is this

[image]

And the resultant coefficient is:

```
[3e-05, 128] initial guessed parameters
[  2.00773153e-04   1.22752179e+02] fitted parameters
```

Because all the data is inside `array`A, `scipy` thinks that the points in the array joins from one point to another, resulting in the end each curve to go back to the origin, which is also the start of subsequent curves.

How should I code in `python` , such that `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` knows that the data in the array consists of multiple curves, instead of it being one single conjoined data? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you export the array from excel?  Is it already in this format or did the export out of excel then import into python cause it to be in this format?  Specifically, I want to know if this data was originally in three separate columns.

Comment: @cosmosis the data is within i one spreadsheet, so it is already in this format. I've edited the code to show how I import from excel.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Have you tried reading in each column separately, for example `x_column = sheet.col_values(0)`, since that is the format that is most useful for what you are trying to accomplish?  It will require a revision of your `func` function definition, but should be easier in general.

Comment: It's matplotlib that connect points if the data is in one array. I think what you want is to plot a different, separate curve of fitted values versus x for each value of y. Either reshape or split up the arrays for x and fitted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your dataset `A` contains all those curves back to back.

Instead, you could split your dataset every time `A[:,0] == 0.00000000e+00`. After splitting it into 6 datasets, you could fit to each separately.

But if I understand your problem correctly, you would also like the parameters `a` and `b` to be the same for every dataset, correct?

In order to help you achieve that, I'm going to shamelessly plug my [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io) package, which wraps `curve_fit` to make such problems easier to solve.

In [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io), you would do the following::

```py
from symfit import Fit, variables, parameters, log, exp

datasets = [A_1, A_2, ...] # I'm going to assume this holds the untangled datasets one through six

xs = variables('x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6')
ys = variables('y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5, y_6')
zs = variables('z_1, ...') # same for z
a, b = parameters('a, b')

model_dict = {
    z: a/(y * b) * log(1 + (y * b/a) * (1 - exp(- a * x))) 
        for x, y, z in zip(xs, ys, zs) 
}
```

This code will create a vector valued model which will allow you to fit to this system of equations simultaneously (With the same instance of `a` and `b` in each!). In order to fit, we can now simply do the following:

```
fit = Fit(model_dict, 
     x_1=datasets[0][:,0], x_2=datasets[1][:,0], ..., 
     y_1=datasets[0][:,1], y_2=datasets[1][:,1], ..., 
     z_1=datasets[0][:,2], z_2=datasets[1][:,2], ...
)
```

I didn't write everything out in full but I hope this gives you an idea of how to complete this. More info can be found in the docs: [symfit docs](http://symfit.readthedocs.io).

As a final remark, note that I have used a symbolic exp and log, not numpy's.

Comment: Hello! I was wondering how you can find the values of "a" and "b" from this? @tBuLi

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the code (appended below) you gave a bit just so it's cut and paste reproducible into Python, in case anyone else wants to to try it.

I'm not sure I understand your question, though.  It appears `x` and `y` are your independent (not dependent) variables and `z` your dependent variable (i.e., the thing computed from each `(x,y)` pair).  In this case, I'd think you'd want a three-dimensional plot - currently, if I'm reading this right, you're plotting `z` vs `x` and not showing `y`.

Assuming you do want to do this, I agree with the comments it'd be best if you split the separate curves apart - I would think the returns-to-zero negatively impact your fit.  You can use `np.where(A[:,0]==0)[0]` to find the indices where `x==0` and use that in a loop to split apart A - though I think `np.split(A,np.where(A[:,0]==0)[0])` does it for you in one line.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(data,a,b):
    return a/(data[:,1]*b)*np.log(1+(data[:,1]*b/a)*(1-np.exp(-a*data[:,0])))

A=np.array(
(0.00000000e+00, 1.49761692e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
 8.85000000e+02, 1.49761692e-05, 6.41362500e-02,
 1.48500000e+03, 1.49761692e-05, 1.19340000e-01,
 2.09000000e+03, 1.49761692e-05, 1.58760000e-01,
 3.36000000e+03, 1.49761692e-05, 2.08080000e-01,
 3.87000000e+03, 1.49761692e-05, 2.16933750e-01,
 6.48000000e+03, 1.49761692e-05, 2.46746250e-01,
 8.22000000e+03, 1.49761692e-05, 2.54700000e-01,
 1.05300000e+04, 1.49761692e-05, 2.59470000e-01,
 1.58250000e+04, 1.49761692e-05, 2.62035000e-01,
 2.37600000e+04, 1.49761692e-05, 2.68751250e-01,
 8.18400000e+04, 1.49761692e-05, 2.92848750e-01,
 0.00000000e+00, 8.57250668e-06, 0.00000000e+00,
 6.75000000e+02, 8.57250668e-06, 4.97436412e-02,
 1.27500000e+03, 8.57250668e-06, 1.27749375e-01,
 1.88000000e+03, 8.57250668e-06, 1.88617039e-01,
 3.15000000e+03, 8.57250668e-06, 2.65089780e-01,
 3.66000000e+03, 8.57250668e-06, 2.90344849e-01,
 6.27000000e+03, 8.57250668e-06, 3.36295316e-01,
 8.01000000e+03, 8.57250668e-06, 3.42702439e-01,
 1.03200000e+04, 8.57250668e-06, 3.65205982e-01,
 1.56150000e+04, 8.57250668e-06, 3.67269626e-01,
 2.35500000e+04, 8.57250668e-06, 3.87296798e-01,
 8.16300000e+04, 8.57250668e-06, 4.43486869e-01,
 0.00000000e+00, 4.26671486e-06, 0.00000000e+00,
 4.65000000e+02, 4.26671486e-06, 2.61407250e-02,
 1.06500000e+03, 4.26671486e-06, 1.22371762e-01,
 1.67000000e+03, 4.26671486e-06, 2.19629475e-01,
 2.94000000e+03, 4.26671486e-06, 3.26680087e-01,
 3.45000000e+03, 4.26671486e-06, 3.34340662e-01,
 6.06000000e+03, 4.26671486e-06, 4.18330575e-01,
 7.80000000e+03, 4.26671486e-06, 4.50631350e-01,
 1.01100000e+04, 4.26671486e-06, 4.55053950e-01,
 1.54050000e+04, 4.26671486e-06, 4.60937587e-01,
 2.33400000e+04, 4.26671486e-06, 5.10770813e-01,
 8.14200000e+04, 4.26671486e-06, 6.12569587e-01,
 0.00000000e+00, 2.13335743e-06, 0.00000000e+00,
 8.55000000e+02, 2.13335743e-06, 1.03773150e-01,
 1.46000000e+03, 2.13335743e-06, 2.21130000e-01,
 2.73000000e+03, 2.13335743e-06, 3.45515625e-01,
 3.24000000e+03, 2.13335743e-06, 3.85634925e-01,
 5.85000000e+03, 2.13335743e-06, 4.76061300e-01,
 7.59000000e+03, 2.13335743e-06, 4.79220300e-01,
 1.51950000e+04, 2.13335743e-06, 5.24709900e-01,
 2.31300000e+04, 2.13335743e-06, 5.64829200e-01,
 8.12100000e+04, 2.13335743e-06, 6.46568325e-01,
 0.00000000e+00, 1.42359023e-06, 0.00000000e+00,
 6.45000000e+02, 1.42359023e-06, 8.03596500e-02,
 1.25000000e+03, 1.42359023e-06, 2.36700000e-01,
 2.52000000e+03, 1.42359023e-06, 4.25941650e-01,
 3.03000000e+03, 1.42359023e-06, 4.61683350e-01,
 5.64000000e+03, 1.42359023e-06, 5.99561100e-01,
 7.38000000e+03, 1.42359023e-06, 6.05952000e-01,
 9.69000000e+03, 1.42359023e-06, 6.16958550e-01,
 1.49850000e+04, 1.42359023e-06, 6.57434250e-01,
 2.29200000e+04, 1.42359023e-06, 6.45954300e-01,
 8.10000000e+04, 1.42359023e-06, 7.79689800e-01,
 0.00000000e+00, 9.36010573e-07, 0.00000000e+00,
 4.35000000e+02, 9.36010573e-07, 3.40200000e-02,
 1.04000000e+03, 9.36010573e-07, 1.91160000e-01,
 2.31000000e+03, 9.36010573e-07, 3.77640000e-01,
 2.82000000e+03, 9.36010573e-07, 4.44240000e-01,
 5.43000000e+03, 9.36010573e-07, 5.50440000e-01,
 7.17000000e+03, 9.36010573e-07, 5.36580000e-01,
 9.48000000e+03, 9.36010573e-07, 5.83740000e-01,
 1.47750000e+04, 9.36010573e-07, 5.87340000e-01,
 2.27100000e+04, 9.36010573e-07, 6.33060000e-01,
 8.07900000e+04, 9.36010573e-07, 7.36200000e-01))
A = A.reshape(len(A)/3, 3)
x= A[:,0]
y= A[:,1]
z= A[:,2]

guess = [3.0e-5, 128 ]  
print guess, 'initial guessed parameters' 

params, pcov = curve_fit(func, A[:,:2], A[:,2], guess)
print params, 'fitted parameters' 

plt.plot(x,func(A,params[0],params[1]),'-r',x,z,'o') 
plt.title('Plot') 
plt.legend(['Fit', 'Data'], loc='lower right', numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```