# Obtained a weird/strange repeated SVR plot instead on a single smooth SVR curve

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and have IMDb movies Datasets (~14000 units). I am trying to predict imdb movie ratings using support vector regression model. For prediction I am using 'ratingCount'column. I plotted a simple plot of 'ratingCount'(X) vs 'imdbRating'(y) using matplotlib and decided to use support vector regression to draw a SVR curve. The curve I got was weird and strange as if it had been repeated again and again on the data plot. I was expecting a single smooth SVR curve to fit in with the data. 
[image: without SVR].
[image: with svr]
Please let me know what is the problem and what is the reason for such weird type of curve as obtained in the pics attached. My python code is simple and clean to the best of my knowledge. . One more thing - I also got an irregular repeated type of curve when I used the polynomial regression model algorithm.I was expecting a single smooth curve but I got strange polynomial curve there also.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    imdb_clean =pd.read_csv(r'E:\pythON\DataSci\GitH\IMDB\Clean_IMDB_3.csv')
    X = imdb_clean.iloc[:, 1:2] .values
    y = imdb_clean.iloc[: ,0:1].values
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    scale_x = StandardScaler()
    scale_y = StandardScaler()
    X = scale_x.fit_transform(X)
    y = scale_y.fit_transform(y)
    from sklearn.svm import SVR
    svr_regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
    svr_regressor.fit(X, y)
    # normal plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.scatter(X, y, color='blue')
    plt.show()


    # svr fitted plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.scatter(X, y, color='blue')
    plt.plot(X, svr_regressor.predict(X), color='black')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib draws the points in the order given. As they are not in ascending order, you get that weird behavior in the plot. You can either sort the dataframe:

```
...
imdb_clean =pd.read_csv(r'E:\pythON\DataSci\GitH\IMDB\Clean_IMDB_3.csv')
imdb_clean = imdb_clean.sort_values(by=imdb_clean.columns[1])
...
```

Or have the sorted values in separate variables, something like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655246/intersecting-matplotlib-graph-with-unsorted-data).

Comment: You explained it right !!. **The problem was because of the plotting nature of matplotlib.** .Sorting the dataframe as required solved the issue. Working absolutely fine now.Thanks a lot!!