# matplotlib.pyplot plot function shows incorrect sequence of points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have just started Python. Esp from core R backgroud, it might be very question.
Here is my data[image]

i just want date value for every month_year value( simple x-y plot) . I tried these options- 
1)

```
plt.plot(grouped_warning_data['month_year'], grouped_warning_data['date'])
```

2)

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(grouped_warning_data['month_year'], grouped_warning_data['date'])
```

[image]

I dont know why sequence( connection to points)  is incorrect. What should i change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersecting matplotlib graph with unsorted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655246/intersecting-matplotlib-graph-with-unsorted-data)

Comment: @damores, yes!! thanks.

Comment: should i delete this one? u r right, solution is already available in your link.